# Is there a way to have VBA excel find a word/string of words in a file and return the value in the cell next to it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that looks up cells and inserts them into another sheet, however, the column and row value don't always stay the same as rows/columns are sometimes added so I can't just look up the specific cell as it can move. I would like to be able to look up the cell to the left which is unique to the file "Total Cost Per Shift" and return the cost in the column to the right. That way no matter what row or column the number is in it will return the correct information.

Here's what I have:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CostingInfo()
Dim wb As Workbook, sht As Worksheet, pth As String

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    pth = "='[" & sht.Parent.Name & "]" & sht.Name & "'!"
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\FS3\Users$\UsersName\Desktop\Costing Template Test.xlsx")
    With wb.Sheets("Open Quote")
        .Range("B3:C3").FormulaR1C1 = pth & "R6C2" ' .Range("L3"). ????
        Set cell = Range("A1:BA350").Find("Total Cost per Shift")
        Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)).Copy
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like VLOOKUP will work for you.

Comment: You can use `Find()` to locate the cell with the unique text, and copy content based on a fixed offset from that.  You may need to loop over the worksheets until you find what you need.

Comment: I was going to do that except that the column/row can move from sheet to sheet it's run on so the VLOOKUP won't always have the first column have the cell words I am looking for.

Comment: you can find the correct columns and still use VLOOKUP to reference those, either with vba or a formula.

Comment: I'm trying use find() but I can't get it to return the data into a specific cell so I'm not sure if any of it's working.
Sub CostingInfo()
Dim wb As Workbook, sht As Worksheet, pth
    
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    pth = "='[" & sht.Parent.Name & "]" & sht.Name & "'!"
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\FS3\Users$\UsersName\Desktop\Costing Template Test.xlsx")
With wb.Sheets("Open Quote")
    .Range("B3:C3").FormulaR1C1 = pth & "R6C2"
    .Range("L3").Set cell = Range("A1:BA350").Find("Total Cost per Shift")
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)).Copy
    
End With
End Sub

Comment: I'd let the Windows operating system take the strain on this, use a command line tool called findstr https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr  then next step is to shell to the command line, use VBA.Shell. for that.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of every coding module.  It will force you to declare your variables, so that you don't make mistakes.  Then click Debug -> Compile VBAProject (Alt+D, Enter) to find the all the syntax/reference mistakes.

Comment: You probably have a problem with the last 2 lines, where you implicitly call `Range`.  What sheet is `Range` on? You need to specify, or it will assume the current `ActiveSheet` and probably mess up.  Is it `sht.Range` or `.Range` (meaning `wb.Sheets("Open Quote").Range`)?

Comment: The .Range items are putting the information onto the macro opened "new" sheet that was created "Costing Template Test.xlsx". The sheet the data I'm looking for is on the original workbook that the macro button is on to open the sheet noted above. I've updated the two rows I believe you area talking about but still getting an error on the .Range

.Range("L3").Set cell = Range("A1:BA350").Find("Total Cost per Shift")
sht.Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)).Copy

Comment: The Range L3 is where I want the data I'm finding from the "Total Cost per Shift" and augmenting the cell over one. L3 is in a different workbook than the workbook I am finding the data in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There isn't a `Range.Set` property/method.  It's invalid, hence why I didn't include it when I tried to fix your question to include the code from your comments.
2. The `.Range` syntax is just a continuation of the `With wb.Sheets("Open Quote")` statement; so `.Range` actually means `wb.Sheets("Open Quote").Range`.
3. When you call `Range` (wihout the `.`), you use an implicit reference to the active worksheet;  Since you just opened a file, which you reference as `wb`, the active worksheet in it is now active, not the sheet/workbook that was active when the subroutine started.

   See reference: [avoiding implicit code](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/10/25/clean-vba-code-pt-2-avoiding-implicit-code/)
4. So, what workbook/sheet is `Range(L3)` supposed to be on?
5. You never test to see `if cell is nothing then` or actually use `cell` anywhere in your code after that.

---

Whenever you run into problems, you should place a Breakpoint (F9) before the problem and use `F8` to step through, one line at a time.

You can mouse over the variables, add a Watch and/or use `Debug.Print` to display values to the immediate window (Ctrl+G).

Try,

```
Debug.Print .Range("L3").Parent & ".Range(" & .Range("L3").Address & ")"
Debug.Print Range("A1:BA350").Parent & ".Range(" & Range("A1:BA350").Address & ")"
Debug.Print cell.Parent & ".Range(" & cell.Address & ")"
```

Please edit the question to include the code that you are currently using.

(It better include `Option Explicit`)